# ASUS Netbook - Loading Ubuntu (replacing Win8.1)

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows, uefi, asus

I'm still new to Ubuntu. I have 3 identical ASUS netbooks and have gotten Ubuntu loaded on 2 of them. The last one came with Win8 and I can't seem to get either the USB stick ISO or the USB disk drive ISO to overwrite the Windows boot manager. I've even gone so far as to tell the BIOS to remove that boot option and yet MS still comes up.

The BIOS will see the USB Stick as a UEFI device and won't see the USB disk drive at all.

I don't seem to be able to format the drive and don't seem to have a way to boot to a different drive.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of Win8.1 and move on to Ubuntu?

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu** (eg. 14.04 LTS or 15.04) are you trying to install?

Comment: Try re-starting **Windows 8.1**, by holding down 'SHIFT'-key when you hit re-start. Then change boot order, to have USB before Boot Manager (under secure boot settings). *However while I know that will solve this for HP laptops, I don't know ASUS as well.*

Comment: I have tried both 14.04 and 15.04. The first ASUS came with 12.04 and I rebuilt it to 14.04 and upgraded to 15.04. The second netbook had XP and was upgraded to 15.04 after wiping XP. This netbook is my first Win8.1and seems much more agressive about keeping the MBR intact and as the Windows boot manager.  I have used the "Shift key" and the BIOS selections to change the boot order to no avail.    Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Although that answer is overly broad.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1.

Create an 'UEFI only' USB installer for Ubuntu **15.04**.

from: 
http://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-make-a-live-usb-stick-using-gnome-disks/

- Open 'Gnome Disks' tool (or search for 'disks')
- Insert 2GB (or 4GB) USB stick into computer (any content will be lost)
- Select the USB stick (be sure you selected the correct device)
- Use the advanced tools (the 'gear' icon) to: “Restore disk image”
- Select the Ubuntu ISO file ..

### Step 2.

Use 'Shift key' method to get Win8.1/BIOS to select that USB device as an UEFI recovery USB. That assumes you BIOS with 'Secure Boot' enabled.

### Step 3.

- Start Ubuntu install, choose 'erase and install Ubuntu' ..

---

**Note:** *I used this method in Feb/Mar to install early 'beta' 15.04 builds (on a Win8.1 laptop).*